# Why would my computer screen just say NO VIDEO INPUT after installing new RAM?

Tags: boot, memory

I have a **asus p5b mx** motherboard and just put in two 2GB **pc2-5300u-555** chips. Now when I turn on my computer:

- keyboard lights flash normally
- "NO VIDEO INPUT" just floats around the screen
- I just hear the fan run, no other activity
- if I click the RESET button, it turns off

What can I do to get my computer to work with this new memory?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had this behavior after one of my sticks of RAM failed.  Remove one at a time, and see if one of the sticks is faulty.

Comment: I replaced a 1 GB stick one at a time and it turned out that one of my new 2 GB sticks was bad, thanks!

Comment: Aw - I was hoping it was just an unseated video card.  Good luck returning the stick!

Answer (score 4):

check to see if perhaps you may have unseated your video card?   also try resetting your CMOS to see if this helps.

Comment: not to mention VLB - the dreaded VESA LOCAL BUS!!  *SHIVERS*

Comment: It's definitely easy enough to unseat that video card - those PCIx slots aren't nearly solid in my opinion as the old agp, pci, and isa slots

Answer (score 3):

Is the monitor plugged into the computer securely? Many monitors will show something like this to show that the monitor's working, but the computer isn't.

Comment: Another good suggestion here - basically double check everything is seated properly and plugged in securely.

Answer (score 2):

If you have faulty elements, the POST usually beeps.
Is your PC speaker disconnected?
If so, it might help to fix that for future cases.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have more info on the memory?  It just might not be compatible.  The board may be having some issue with its on board video.  I'd suggest clearing the BIOS and trying again.  Try the memory one at a time, and also with 1 of the old modules.  It may help isolate a compatibility issue or just a bad stick.